# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design

Hi Guys,

We just launched the new design for the Math site. Grats, and thank you for your [design feedback](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/design-ideas-for-mathematics-site).

A few changes I made from the original design mock up I showed you, per on your input:

- Moved logo left to the type in header.
- Removed "∴" from accepted answer background. I used a "✓" instead.
- Restyled badges to look more generic and theme fitting.
- Changed question title link to blue(more like Beta's) instead of dark red.

I also created 404 and Captcha images based on your ideas. I still need to do the Error one.

I didn't get to put in as many "mathy elements" as I originally intended to. But I also didn't want to do it for the sake of doing it, and get in the way of usability and the clean design. If you can think of more ways to improve the design, please let me know.

If you see any CSS/styling issues, please create a new post for the bug report. Tag it with "Design" and "Bug" so I can track them easily.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again for your work! The new design looks good. I still have some suggestions I'll post when I have time, but for now I'd like to quickly bring this thread to your attention: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/944/why-is-the-font-color-not-black ...Actually, I think that goes for a lot of text on the site; it's very light in colour.

Comment: I like it! I notified a little bug.

Comment: @Jin:  I can no longer easily read anything with the change to smaller fonts (which also appears to affect LaTeX). This also messes up carefully cratfted formatting in many posts. Was there some need to switch?  This comment regards  the main site, not meta.

Comment: @Bill are you talking about the font-size in the question and answer body text?

Comment: @Jin: The blue titles look better than the prior  red, but they're extremely washed-out/fuzzy on my laptop  lcd.   The  "votes" and "views" fields on the questions page are so faint that they're hard to read.

Comment: Looks nice; it's a clean design. Where's the favicon, out of curiosity?

Comment: @Jin: Yes the smaller fonts and change of fonts in answers; it also appears to similarly shrink LaTeX rendered items  (comparing before and after for the same answer).

Comment: @Noldorin they're deployed, but chances are cached by your browser. you can go to http://sstatic.net/math/img/favicon.ico and http://sstatic.net/mathmeta/img/favicon.ico and hard refresh there.

Comment: @Jin: Ah, but of course. Cheers for that.

Comment: @Jin:  Particularly troublesome with the smaller LaTeX rendering are  exponents and subscripts - they are now  illegible in many instances.

Comment: Bill i have bumped up the text size in question/answer post body. the change will be in the next deployment.

Comment: @Jin: Thanks for the font bump.  In the question page, the gravatar and modifcation time are needlessly causing the question to consume too much height - with much wasted whitespace. Could they be laid out horizontally,  perhaps below the votes,answers,views (also horizontally), so to get more questions displayed per page.  There is too much wasted whitespace currently, esp given that most modern displays are widescreen format. This would allow one to peruse an entire question in a single horizontal eyescan, vs. the up-and-down and back-and-forth eye scanning needed to scan it as is.

Comment: @Jin: The recent badges column stands out too much compared to other more important elements. Does anyone even pay any attention to recent badges?  When in-view it draws one's eye away from the more-important questions column because it is so bold.

Comment: @bill all sites' css themes use Stackoverflow's HTML. If you wish to have it removed, you can put in a feature request on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Jin:  It's not clear to me which of various questions you are replying to above.

Comment: @bill it was for the recent badge column one. maybe start a new post with your requests? :)

Comment: @Jin: Don't you have control over the background color of the badges? If so why not make it more subdued so they don't' stand out so much next to the questions (note this is on the topl-level site page, not the questions page).

Comment: @Bill I thought you meant removal of that whole section. SO and many other SE sites, including the previous Beta theme all use darker shade badge treatment, no one I know of has complained. But I think your issues is about either they should be on the question listing page at all? I'm using a darker shade as a convention.

Comment: @Jin: Go to the main page and scroll down so that the badges occupy the whole rightmost column. Now scan the questions and note how the boldness of the badges has visual gravity that draws the eye away from the questions. The badges should be less bold to reverse the visual gravitational flow. This is less important to me than other points I mentioned but since it's a trivial patch why not fix it?

Comment: Is [this behavior](http://i.imgur.com/3UiIu.png) on a user page intentional?

Comment: I also see the behavior J.M. shows, on Firefox 3.6.9 even with the browser maximized to 1680px wide.

Comment: @J.M. You should probably start a new post about it.

Comment: Well, it's not as annoying as that other thing I posted about, just weird. I'll try to look at other user pages first to confirm this observation.

Comment: @JM i'm looking into that problem

Comment: @Jin: please see my post [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1006/242) for a rendering inconsistency between the preview and final post. Btw, what protocol do you prefer to draw your attention to posts about design bugs? Comments @you, tags, or ...?

Comment: @bill you're doing the right thing by starting a new post tagged with Design and Bug. Thanks.