# How can I get the *.svg version of the logo of math.SE?

Tags: support, feature-request, design

I want to put the logo of math.SE to my website linking to my profile, and the template I'm using uses svg versions of the logos; at least if I have the svg version of a logo, I know how to use it in my website, so

> How can I get the *.svg version of the logo of math.SE ?

Comment: Do you know about "flair"?

Comment: @quid No, what is that ? How can I use it to solve my problem ?

Comment: @quid Oh I know those, but that would not do the job.

Comment: On the main site, If I right click and save the logo (I assume you mean the one with 6 red squares plus the text 'Mathematics'). It is an 286x32 svg....

Comment: When I choose "Inspect" in the browser, I get this file: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/math/Img/sprites.svg?v=fa2277060fb6

Comment: So using a vector image editor like Inkscape, one can extract the site's logo.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank a lot; I was able to extract the 6 red cubes from that .svg file

Comment: You can also find the logo in these posts (although not in svg format): [Design Ideas for Mathematics Site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/963) and [Do those red cubes aligned circulary next to MATHEMATICS have any mathematical significance?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13398)

Comment: One caveat, you might want to check if this is allowed. The CC license is for user content not for the graphics etc. "All materials displayed or performed on the public Network, including but not limited to text, graphics, logos, tools, photographs, images, illustrations, software or source code, audio and video, and animations (collectively “Network Content”) (other than Network Content posted by individual “Subscriber Content”) are the property of Stack Overflow and/or third parties and are protected by United States and international copyright laws (“Stack Overflow Content”)."

Comment: @quid I remember discussion around copyright of the logo [on MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3645/copyright-of-mathoverflow-logo). Was there some similar discussion on this meta?

Comment: @MartinSleziak see for example https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22117/what-are-the-rules-on-using-the-stack-overflow-logo This  should apply to math.se too (MO is different).

Comment: @MartinSleziak turns out there is actually an official site just about this https://stackoverflow.com/company/logos . Sorry for the double post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that svg-file with the logo is available here: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/math/Img/sprites.svg?v=fa2277060fb6 
I got the link after choosing "Inspect" and "Sources" in Google Chrome, while viewing the site.

It seems that svg format is not supported as a format which can be used in posts. So here is at least a screenshot showing the content of the svg file:

[image: sprites]

You can also find the logo in these posts (although not in svg format): [Design Ideas for Mathematics Site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/963) and [Do those red cubes aligned circulary next to MATHEMATICS have any mathematical significance?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13398)

---

As mentioned in the comment, you should keep in mind copyright/trademark issues. See also: [What are the rules on using the Stack Overflow logo?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22117), SO page with [logos](https://stackoverflow.com/company/logos) and [Guidelines for the Use of the Stack Exchange, Inc. Trademarks](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/trademark-guidance).

Since you have mentioned that you want to use this to link to your account, the fact that [flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/flair/info) can be used for this purpose should be mentioned.

(Both these issues were raised in the comments by quid - I think they are important enough to be mentioned in an answer.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Mathematics logo, I cut down the svg HTML code to be:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="494" height="500" viewBox="0 0 494 500">
   <path d="M106.6 44.8H87.8v-1.9c.6 0 1.2-.1 2-.2s1.4-.2 1.6-.4c.6-.2 1-.6 1.3-1s.4-1 .4-1.6V13.8L81.3 44.3h-3.1c-.1-.5-.5-1.6-1.1-3.2-.6-1.6-1-2.9-1.4-3.8L67 13.5v21.1c0 2 .1 3.6.4 4.6s.7 1.8 1.3 2.3c.4.3 1.1.7 2.2 1s1.8.5 2.2.5v1.9H58.2V43c.4 0 1.1-.2 2-.3.9-.2 1.7-.5 2.3-.9.6-.5 1.1-1.2 1.3-2.3s.3-2.6.3-4.6V17.6c0-1-.1-1.9-.4-2.6-.3-.7-.7-1.2-1.2-1.6-.7-.5-1.3-.8-2-1l-2.1-.3v-1.9h16L82.9 33l7.2-18.5c.2-.7.5-1.5.7-2.4s.3-1.6.4-1.9h15.3v1.9c-.5 0-1.1.1-1.6.2-.6.1-1.1.2-1.6.4-.6.2-1.1.5-1.3 1-.2.5-.3 1-.3 1.5v24.5c0 .6.1 1.1.3 1.5.2.4.6.7 1.3 1 .3.1.9.3 1.6.4.7.1 1.3.2 1.7.3v1.9zm42.1 0h-18.9v-1.9c.9-.1 1.9-.2 3.1-.5 1.2-.3 1.8-.6 1.8-.9v-.4c0-.2-.1-.4-.2-.7l-3-7.2h-12c-.3.7-.6 1.4-.9 2.3-.3.9-.6 1.7-.9 2.4-.3.9-.5 1.6-.5 2-.1.4-.1.7-.1.9 0 .5.4 1 1.2 1.3.8.4 2.1.6 3.9.8v1.9H108v-1.9c.5 0 1.1-.1 1.8-.3.7-.1 1.2-.3 1.6-.6.7-.4 1.2-.9 1.7-1.4.5-.6.8-1.2 1.2-2 1.9-4.6 3.8-9.1 5.7-13.7 1.9-4.6 4-9.6 6.3-15.2h4.9c3.2 7.8 5.7 14 7.5 18.6s3.3 8.3 4.6 11.3c.2.5.5.9.8 1.3.3.4.8.8 1.4 1.1.5.3 1 .5 1.6.6s1.1.2 1.6.2v2zm-18.2-14l-5-12.5-4.9 12.5h9.9zm51.7-10.7h-1.9c-.5-1.5-1.3-3.1-2.4-4.8-1.1-1.7-2.1-2.6-3.1-2.7-.5-.1-1.2-.1-1.9-.2-.8 0-1.4-.1-2-.1h-1.1v27.2c0 .6.1 1.1.3 1.5s.6.8 1.2 1.1c.4.1 1 .3 1.7.5.8.2 1.5.3 2 .3v1.9h-19.3v-1.9c.5 0 1.1-.1 2-.2.9-.1 1.4-.2 1.7-.3.6-.3 1.1-.6 1.3-1s.3-1 .3-1.6V12.4h-1c-.6 0-1.2 0-2 .1-.8 0-1.4.1-1.9.2-.9.1-2 1-3.1 2.7s-1.9 3.3-2.4 4.8h-1.9v-9.9h33.5v9.8zm45.3 24.7h-18.7v-1.9c.4 0 1-.1 1.8-.1.8-.1 1.3-.2 1.6-.3.6-.2 1-.6 1.2-1s.3-.9.3-1.5V28.1h-14.8v11.7c0 .6.1 1 .4 1.5.2.4.6.8 1.2 1 .3.1.8.3 1.6.4.7.1 1.4.2 1.8.3v1.9h-18.7V43c.4 0 1-.1 1.8-.2s1.4-.2 1.7-.3c.6-.2 1-.5 1.2-1 .2-.4.3-.9.3-1.5V15.5c0-.6-.1-1-.3-1.4s-.6-.7-1.3-1a14.5 14.5 0 0 0-3.6-.9v-1.9h18.7v1.9c-.5 0-1.1.1-1.8.2s-1.2.3-1.6.4c-.6.2-1.1.5-1.3 1s-.3 1-.3 1.5v10.3h14.8V15.5c0-.6-.1-1-.3-1.4s-.6-.7-1.3-1c-.4-.2-1-.4-1.7-.5-.7-.2-1.3-.3-1.7-.3v-1.9h18.7v1.9c-.5 0-1.1.1-1.8.2s-1.2.2-1.8.4-1 .5-1.2 1-.3 1-.3 1.5v24.5c0 .6.1 1.1.3 1.5s.6.7 1.2 1c.4.2 1 .3 1.7.4.7.1 1.3.2 1.8.2v1.8h.4zm35-25.8h-1.9c-.5-1.3-1.3-2.6-2.4-4-1.2-1.3-2.3-2.1-3.4-2.4-.5-.1-1.2-.2-2-.2h-7.2v13.3h3.6c.9 0 1.7-.1 2.4-.3.7-.2 1.4-.6 2-1.2.4-.4.8-1 1.1-2 .4-.9.6-1.8.7-2.5h1.9v14.4h-1.9c-.1-.7-.3-1.5-.7-2.6-.4-1-.8-1.7-1.1-2.1-.5-.6-1.2-1-1.9-1.2s-1.6-.3-2.5-.3h-3.6v10c0 1 .1 1.9.2 2.5.2.6.4 1.1.9 1.4.4.3 1 .5 1.7.6s1.7.1 2.9.1h2c.8 0 1.5-.1 2.1-.1.7-.1 1.3-.2 1.9-.4s1-.4 1.3-.7c.8-.8 1.7-2 2.6-3.6s1.6-2.9 1.9-3.7h1.8l-.7 10.8h-32.5v-1.9c.5 0 1.1-.1 1.9-.2.8-.1 1.3-.2 1.7-.3.6-.3 1-.6 1.2-1s.3-.9.3-1.5V15.5c0-.6-.1-1.1-.3-1.5s-.6-.7-1.3-1c-.4-.2-1-.4-1.8-.5-.8-.2-1.3-.3-1.7-.3v-1.9h30.7V19h.1zm54 25.8h-18.8v-1.9c.6 0 1.2-.1 2-.2s1.4-.2 1.6-.4c.6-.2 1-.6 1.3-1s.4-1 .4-1.6V13.8l-11.9 30.4H288c-.1-.5-.5-1.6-1.1-3.2-.6-1.6-1-2.9-1.4-3.8l-8.8-23.8v21.1c0 2 .1 3.6.4 4.6s.7 1.8 1.3 2.3c.4.3 1.1.7 2.2 1s1.8.5 2.2.5v1.9H268v-1.9c.4 0 1.1-.2 2-.3.9-.2 1.7-.5 2.3-.9.6-.5 1.1-1.2 1.3-2.3.2-1.1.3-2.6.3-4.6V17.6c0-1-.1-1.9-.4-2.6-.3-.7-.7-1.2-1.2-1.6-.7-.5-1.3-.8-2-1s-1.4-.2-2.1-.3v-1.9h16l8.5 22.8 7.2-18.5c.2-.7.5-1.5.7-2.4s.3-1.6.4-1.9h15.3v1.9c-.5 0-1.1.1-1.6.2-.6.1-1.1.2-1.6.4-.6.2-1.1.5-1.3 1-.2.5-.3 1-.3 1.5v24.5c0 .6.1 1.1.3 1.5.2.4.6.7 1.3 1 .3.1.9.3 1.6.4.7.1 1.3.2 1.7.3v1.9h.1zm42.1 0h-18.9v-1.9c.9-.1 1.9-.2 3.1-.5s1.8-.6 1.8-.9v-.4c0-.2-.1-.4-.2-.7l-3-7.2h-12c-.3.7-.6 1.4-.9 2.3-.3.9-.6 1.7-.9 2.4-.3.9-.5 1.6-.5 2-.1.4-.1.7-.1.9 0 .5.4 1 1.2 1.3.8.4 2.1.6 3.9.8v1.9H318v-1.9c.5 0 1.1-.1 1.8-.3.7-.1 1.2-.3 1.6-.6.7-.4 1.2-.9 1.7-1.4.5-.6.8-1.2 1.2-2 1.9-4.6 3.8-9.1 5.7-13.7 1.9-4.6 4-9.6 6.3-15.2h4.9c3.2 7.8 5.7 14 7.5 18.6s3.3 8.3 4.6 11.3c.2.5.5.9.8 1.3.3.4.8.8 1.4 1.1.5.3 1 .5 1.6.6s1.1.2 1.6.2v2h-.1zm-18.2-14l-5-12.5-4.9 12.5h9.9zm51.7-10.7h-1.9c-.5-1.5-1.3-3.1-2.4-4.8s-2.1-2.6-3.1-2.7c-.5-.1-1.2-.1-1.9-.2-.8 0-1.4-.1-2-.1h-1.1v27.2c0 .6.1 1.1.3 1.5.2.4.6.8 1.2 1.1.4.1 1 .3 1.7.5.8.2 1.5.3 2 .3v1.9h-19.3v-1.9c.5 0 1.1-.1 2-.2.9-.1 1.4-.2 1.7-.3.6-.3 1.1-.6 1.3-1 .2-.4.3-1 .3-1.6V12.4h-1.1c-.6 0-1.2 0-2 .1-.8 0-1.4.1-1.9.2-.9.1-2 1-3.1 2.7s-1.9 3.3-2.4 4.8h-1.9v-9.9H392l.1 9.8zm22 24.7h-19.2v-1.9c.4 0 1.1-.1 1.9-.1.9-.1 1.4-.2 1.8-.3.6-.2 1-.6 1.2-1s.3-.9.3-1.5V15.5c0-.6-.1-1-.3-1.5-.2-.4-.6-.8-1.2-1-.4-.2-1-.3-1.7-.5-.8-.2-1.4-.3-2-.4v-1.9h19.2v1.9c-.5 0-1.1.1-1.8.2s-1.4.2-1.9.4c-.6.2-1.1.5-1.3 1-.2.4-.3 1-.3 1.5v24.5c0 .6.1 1.1.3 1.5.2.4.6.8 1.3 1 .3.1.9.3 1.7.4.8.1 1.5.2 2 .3v1.9zm22.4 1c-2.5 0-4.9-.4-7.1-1.2s-4.1-2-5.8-3.6c-1.6-1.5-2.9-3.4-3.8-5.7s-1.4-4.7-1.4-7.4.5-5.2 1.4-7.5 2.2-4.3 3.9-5.9c1.7-1.6 3.7-2.9 6-3.8 2.3-.9 4.8-1.4 7.5-1.4 1.9 0 3.7.2 5.2.7 1.6.5 2.9 1 4 1.6l1.5-1.3h2.1l.2 12.6h-2.1c-1.2-3.9-2.7-6.7-4.4-8.5a8.26 8.26 0 0 0-6.2-2.7c-3.1 0-5.4 1.3-7 4s-2.4 6.5-2.4 11.4c0 2.8.3 5.1.8 7.1.5 1.9 1.3 3.5 2.1 4.7.9 1.2 2.1 2.1 3.3 2.7 1.3.6 2.7.9 4.3.9 2.3 0 4.3-.6 6.1-1.9 1.8-1.2 3.4-3.1 4.9-5.6l2.1 1.3c-.7 1.4-1.5 2.7-2.4 3.8s-1.9 2.1-3.1 2.9c-1.3.9-2.7 1.6-4.3 2.1-1.4.4-3.3.7-5.4.7zm33.1 0c-2.1 0-4.1-.3-5.9-.8s-3.4-1.2-4.6-1.9l-1.7 1.7h-2.1l-.3-12.5h2.1c.5 1.2 1.1 2.4 1.8 3.8.7 1.3 1.6 2.5 2.5 3.5 1 1.1 2.1 2 3.3 2.7 1.2.7 2.7 1 4.3 1 2.2 0 3.9-.5 5.1-1.6s1.8-2.4 1.8-4.1c0-1.4-.5-2.5-1.5-3.4s-2.5-1.7-4.6-2.4c-1.4-.4-2.6-.8-3.8-1.2-1.1-.4-2.2-.8-3.2-1.2-2.3-.9-4.1-2.3-5.2-4s-1.7-3.7-1.7-5.8c0-1.4.3-2.7.9-3.9s1.4-2.4 2.6-3.4c1.1-.9 2.4-1.7 4.1-2.3s3.5-.9 5.5-.9c1.9 0 3.7.3 5.4.8 1.7.5 3 1.1 4 1.6l1.5-1.5h2.1l.2 11.8H480c-.5-1.3-1.1-2.6-1.7-3.9-.7-1.3-1.4-2.4-2.1-3.3-.8-.9-1.7-1.7-2.8-2.3-1-.6-2.3-.8-3.7-.8-1.8 0-3.2.5-4.3 1.5a4.8 4.8 0 0 0-1.7 3.7c0 1.4.5 2.5 1.5 3.4s2.5 1.7 4.5 2.3c1.2.4 2.4.8 3.7 1.2 1.3.4 2.4.8 3.3 1.2 2.4.9 4.2 2.2 5.4 3.8 1.2 1.6 1.8 3.6 1.8 6 0 1.5-.4 2.9-1 4.3-.7 1.4-1.6 2.6-2.8 3.5-1.3 1-2.8 1.8-4.5 2.4-1.7.7-3.7 1-6 1z" fill="#0F3559"/> 
   <path fill="#CB181F" d="M32.2 5.1l-8.7 5.1-8.8-5.1L23.4 0z"/>
   <path fill="#B6161C" d="M32.2 5.1v10.1l-8.7 5.1V10.2z"/>
   <path fill="#7F0F13" d="M23.5 10.2v10.1l-8.9-5.1.1-10.1z"/>
   <path fill="#CB181F" d="M46.8 13.5L38 18.6l-8.8-5.1L38 8.4z"/>
   <path fill="#B6161C" d="M46.8 13.5v10.1L38 28.7V18.6z"/>
   <path fill="#CB181F" d="M46.8 30.3L38 35.4l-8.8-5.1 8.8-5.1z"/>
   <path fill="#B6161C" d="M46.8 30.3v10.1L38 45.5V35.4z"/>
   <path fill="#CB181F" d="M32.2 38.8l-8.7 5.1-8.8-5.1 8.7-5.1z"/>
   <path fill="#B6161C" d="M32.2 38.8v10.1L23.5 54V43.9z"/>
   <path fill="#CB181F" d="M17.6 30.3l-8.8 5.1L0 30.3l8.8-5.1z"/>
   <path fill="#B6161C" d="M17.6 30.3v10.1l-8.8 5.1V35.4z"/>
   <path fill="#CB181F" d="M17.6 13.5l-8.7 5.1-8.8-5.1 8.7-5.1z"/>
   <path fill="#B6161C" d="M17.6 13.5v10.1l-8.7 5.1V18.6z"/>
</svg>
```

Let me know if it works, because it works for me, but I don't know if it will work for others.  Otherwise if you want all of the other details, follow Martin Sleziak's answer.

TIP: If you would like just the logo and not the "Mathematics" letters in there, just remove the first "< path>" line.