# Community Ads for 2021

Tags: discussion, community-ads

**September update:** Community Ads are now live network-wide. All ads with a score of 6 or higher, or with a score of 4 or higher *and* no downvotes will be displayed (except for any that have a note from the CM Team explaining why it wasn't selected). Go to [the main post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364556/208518) for a list of the ads that are being displayed. And stay tuned for 2022's edition for the next opportunity to submit more ad proposals!

---

**AUGUST NOTE:** This post has now been locked and new submissions are not being accepted. Ad submissions are now undergoing review by the Community Team, and this question will be updated once the ads are live.

---

We're almost halfway through 2021, and [in case you missed it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364556/208518), Community Promotion Ads are gonna be a bit different this time! **TL;DR: submit and vote for ad proposals before August 2nd!**

#### What are Community Ads?

Community Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, or on other sites in the network. They can show up in the right sidebar, or in banners in question pages. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be considered by [the Community Management Team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/208518) to be displayed.

#### Why do we have Community Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. The goal of this initiative is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join. You may want to promote external resources, or Meta guidance for newcomers, for instance.

This initiative has an added goal of providing your community with *an opportunity to showcase exemplary questions from your main site, as well as frequently-linked-to guides from your Meta site*. While the latter makes sense to be shown solely on this site, the former can be shown all across the network. These should avoid hot button topics, and instead focus more on evergreen questions that show what your community’s all about.

#### Why do we reset the ads?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. Historically, we've reset the ads every year — since this is the first run of a new format, we'll run the ads collected in this post through the end of 2021 and reassess the rotation cycle then.

The community ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a previous exposure.

#### Are there restrictions to the ads I can post?

All proposed ads need to abide by [our Code of Conduct](/conduct). [Our ad creative guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/advertising/guidelines) also generally apply (note that the first 2 bullet points on the “Tracking” section do not apply, and a lot of the guidelines surrounding claims, comparisons, proof, etc., while still applicable, may not be particularly relevant). Finally, ads can not be promoting products nor soliciting programmer time or resources for: knowledge sharing or collaboration tools for technologists, or for sites where ad buyers are primarily targeting technologists.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored:

1. **Each answer must relate to a single ad submission.** Please do not post multiple ad submissions in the same answer.
2. All answers must be in one of the below formats:

   1. If you have an image for the ad you want to display on this site (must be the case for ads to external sources):

   ```
   [![Image name. Example: "community_ad_name_300x250"][1]][2]

     [1]: https://image-url
     [2]: https://clickthrough-url
   ```

   2. If you want to create an ad for a question from your main or meta site, to be advertised on this or other sites in the network (staff will generate a frame for the ad with this site's theme, for brand consistency):

   ```
   Question title  
   Question URL
   Ad size (right sidebar or banner ads)
   Site(s) to be displayed in. Can be:
     - "self" for ads to be displayed on this site
     - "all" for ads to be displayed all over the network
     - a specific subset of sites
   ```
3. Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels for right sidebar ads or 728 x 90 pixels for banner ads. Images can be double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF, PNG, or JPG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Selection process

**This post will remain open for ad submissions and voting until August 2nd**. At that point, the question will be closed/locked, and no more ad submissions will be accepted. For ad submissions to be considered for selection by the Community Management Team, they must have **a minimum score of 6 at the time the post was closed/locked for submissions.** Given this is the first run with this new format, we may adjust the score threshold to be a bit lower if we see ads struggling to get to it (especially if the ads are not getting downvotes) by the time submissions and voting are closed.

#### Reporting statistics

Once this cycle is over, at the end of 2021, the Community Management Team will provide you with reporting statistics, as described in the "reporting" section of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364556/208518).

---

Feel free to use the question's comment section to ask for any clarifications.

Comment: "Finally, ads can not be promoting products nor soliciting programmer time or resources for: knowledge sharing or collaboration tools for technologists, or for sites where ad buyers are primarily targeting technologists." I'm unable to parse this sentence. Could you please clarify what this means in plain English?

Comment: That clause is basically there to make it explicit in the initiative rules that SE holds the right to disallow this free advertising space to be used to promote products or initiatives that may be competitive to our products. Does that make sense, @TheAmplitwist?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you very much, @JNat :)

Comment: @JNat if the image doesn't look good then can we use dimensions that are not specified in question

Comment: Like I mentioned, @JitendraSingh, please stick to the sizes specified in the question. If you submit proposals that don't conform to those guidelines, they will not be displayed even if they reach the minimum score threshold for being displayed.

Comment: @JNat okay thanks for clarification

Answer (score 29):

[image: Approach0.xyz, a math-aware search engine]

Comment: [Repost](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31299/111262) from last year.

Comment: I have upscaled the ad so that it is sharper on hi-res displays using some "ML" rescaling feature of a photo editor and a little manual editing. (I could not figure out what fonts you used.) Feel free to revert

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you! I made it a smaller size because the right sidebar ads looked good to me in the past. I think this larger size will become a banner ad? Do you know where it will be placed?

Comment: You are welcome, thank you for Approach Zero :) it should still be at the same place (right side), but if your display is higher dpi then in previous years I think this would look nicer. (They are changing the code this year so that may not be true anymore.) Banner ads need to be shorter and wider, 728x90.

Comment: @CalvinKhor That is great! I like this one, it does look brighter. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you like it, ML is great! It was more accurate than putting the logo in a photo2svg converter

Comment: Yup, the ML is likely using deep learning, and I recently learned, deep learning can be viewed as a good (iterative) optimization for compression (from [this study](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z2bQXO2mYPo&t=4208s)).

Answer (score 16):

[image: Sage: open-source mathematical software]

Comment: For online use: [Sage Cell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/)

Answer (score 14):

[image: Link to all review queues for Math.SE]

Comment: idea clearly stolen from https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13638/96668

Answer (score 13):

Need help with math formatting in your post?

[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

right sidebar

self

Comment: Make this into an image and you'll get approved pretty fast.

Comment: @DonThousand It is mentioned that "staff will generate a frame for the ad with this site's theme, for brand consistency"; so, I only gave the details requested in the format of point 2.2 under "How does it work?" in the OP.

Comment: Nice idea. I've put together one for Physics [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13655/8563). That can probably be adapted for this site if needed (though y'all should probably just take advantage of the SE offer to produce graphics).

Comment: @E.P. , it is possible to add physics.SE to this answer, if you want the SE graphics. The logistics of getting that approved by the Physics.SE community sounds impossible though (and I'm not sure letting sites vote on ads to appear on **other** sites was a good idea)

Comment: Also, in [your](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13655/96668) graphic, the blown-up MSE logo is a little [off](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32901/asymmetry-in-mathematics-stack-exchange-logo) :) Here's hoping the staff generated image will be symmetrical.

Answer (score 12):

[image: GAP 4, open source system for discrete computational algebra]

Comment: Reposting [a reasonably popular ad](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31317/80734) from last year

Comment: Thanks @Calvin !

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov I see you’ve posted the ad many years now. I feel like I have overstepped some boundary somewhere by posting so many answers, but decided to act because of the limited time available to post ads this year round. So to receive thanks is somewhat a relief :) you’re welcome

Comment: Perfect! I haven't seen the call for ads till today, and your repost of the GAP ad was very helpful!

Answer (score 11):

[image: Overleaf, free online collaborative LaTeX editor and template gallery]

Comment: Reposting a [reasonably popular ad](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31300/80734) from last year

Answer (score 10):

[image: Detexify, automated LaTeX symbol recognition]

Comment: [source](https://www.google.com/search?q=http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html+ads&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN920IN920&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwju-9bI6t3xAhUX63MBHaLQDMsQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1280&bih=609)

Comment: Why downvote? For any disagreement regarding ad? For bad ad?

Comment: Most posts are getting a fair number of downvotes. Don't sweat it.

Answer (score 9):

Need help asking a question?

[How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

right sidebar

self

Answer (score 7):

[image: Looking to make commutative diagrams? Try quiver]

Answer (score 7):

Want to ask a homework question but don't know what the rules are?

[How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/876009)

right sidebar

self

Comment: I have written this answer based on the inspiration of [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33764/876009)

Comment: It should be "Want to ask a homework question but don't know what the rules are?". But this is also a little long...maybe "What are the rules for asking about homework?"

Comment: @CalvinKhor I choose the first one you suggested

Answer (score 7):

[image: Real not complex, curated list of free resources to study mathematics]

Comment: reposting a [reasonably popular ad](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31398/80734) from last year

Answer (score 7):

[image: Cocalc, Collaborative Calculation in the Cloud]

Comment: Reposting [a reasonably popular](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31310/80734) ad from last year

Comment: For those unaware, Cocalc is the latest incarnation of Sage Math Cloud (which in turn was the replacement for sagenb.org).

Answer (score 7):

[image: Math3d.org: Create, animate, and share beautiful math in your browser]

Comment: Reposting [a reasonably popular ad](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31304/80734) from last year

Answer (score 6):

[image: Functors.net, a blog community for mathematicians]

Answer (score 5):

[image: SciLag]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange]

Comment: Reposting a [reasonably popular ad](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31305/80734) from last year (actually, this is a mild re-do to have newer stats, and I kept a newer question I got when I took a new screenshot. The ad links to the New Questions page; the question in the picture is [this one](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/21131/why-is-differential-calculus-often-presented-before-integral-calculus?r=SearchResults&s=1|81.8120))

Answer (score 3):

[image: TeX Paste – share equations across the Internet]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Common topics on Matter Modeling SE]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: FYI, the site is now considerably larger than the statistics indicate in that picture. Here is a more current screenshot from https://stackexchange.com/sites : https://i.imgur.com/bAqvlxO.png I guess it should not be too hard to adjust the image for this (remark: the font is different since SE changed to system fonts)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Notation is a tool of thought!]

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yeah, I noticed the scrolling issue too, and I've put it on the todo list, but thanks for the feedback. We are going to focus on TryAPL issues next week, which should be plenty of time before these ads go live. I'd be happy to discuss the choice of `*` but these comments aren't the place for it. Maybe you can ping me in the [APL Orchard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard) chat room?

Comment: Just adding this Wikipedia link here, since this is my first time coming across APL, and maybe there are others like me: [APL (programming language)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language))

Comment: @Adám sorry for the reaction comment :) I might eventually ask you about APL there

Answer (score -2):

[image: Notation is a tool of thought!]

Comment: Isn't this the same ads as the one you just posted?

Comment: @ArcticChar One is a banner and one is a side bar ad.

Answer (score -9):

[image: Mathematics Educators Beta]

Comment: This room has been created to connect people interested in online collaborations ( study group & research group).Please first read [the guideline](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113060/conversation/the-guideline) of the room. If you have any question, request, suggestion, criticism, ... about this project, please send your messages in [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110690/meta-stack-exchange).

Comment: Why this being downvoted?

Comment: I would recommend adding some text to the image, to explain what the ad is about.

Comment: I thought it was a dating site for math people at first...

Comment: @qwr highkey would be interested in that.