# What is the mathematics behind MSE logo?

Tags: discussion, design

This is the logo of our main website.

[image]

What is the mathematics behind this logo. I mean the logo should have some mathematical significance or idea. I can only see six cubes arranged in a pattern.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See here: [Do those red cubes aligned circulary next to MATHEMATICS have any mathematical significance?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13398) and [Design Ideas for Mathematics Site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/963).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks Martin. I love your enthusiasm and work you do to keep this website clean of duplicate questions and other related works. :)